# sharepoint calculated column hyperlink not coming if return type is Single line of text

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column, hyperlink

I have a list with country name and country code, I am using the list while creating a form and selecting the country code when a user selects a third column 'select country' which is a calculated column. And I am passing the country code to a javascript-->

```
 ="<a href='javascript:SelectCountry("&countryCode&")'>Select Country</a>"
```

**But the issue is that** when the return type is 'single line of text' no hyperlink is coming, and if I select return type as 'Number' hyperlink is creating and in my case my return type is countrycode(which is like CZ,US,IN,CN etc) which is not number.

How can I implement a calculated column having return type 'single line of text' and the column should be a hyperlink.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I implement a calculated column having return type 'single line of text' and the column should be a hyperlink.

Not, outputting HTML is an undocumented feature that only works with non-Text datatypes

**Datatypes**:

- Single Line of Text
  outputs the Calculation result as bare text (showing all HTML tags)
- Number
  outputs correct HTML, but wrapped in an extra DIV, aligning the result to the right
- Date
  outputs correct HTML, aligned to the left

Your problem is your HTML syntax is missing quotes, you need extra doublequotes so the Formula outputs a single doublequote:

```
="<a href='alert(""" & countryCode & """)'>Select Country</a>"
```

Better to read with reversed use of quotes:

```
="<a href=""alert('" & countryCode & "')"">Select Country</a>"
```

*used the alert for Proof of Concept, you can use any JavaScript*

Comment: Thanks for the answer but result is still the same hyperlink shown as HTML.

Comment: And your Datatype is Number or Date? What does ``="<h1>Hello</H1"`` output? And remember this does NOT work on Forms, only in Views